# submit form - jquery problem

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to raise a click event on a submit button in a html form.
I use the .click() jquery to catch the click event and return true at the end of the function.
When I click on the submit button, the jquery functions are raised and a callback is executed, but the $_POST array is empty.

How can I fix this?

code:

```
<form action="index.php?p=searchexlibris&amp;t=palabre" method="post" id="frmSearchexlibris">
<input type="text" name="palabre" id="palabre" value="" /> 
<input class="searchbutton" id="exlibrisbutton" type="submit" value="Buscar" />
</form>
```

In javascript functions: 
    $('#exlibrisbutton').click(function(){
           enableDisableFormExlibris('exlibrisbutton',false);
           return true;
    });

In the function that catches the submit I get an empty $_POST, while the post works when I dont call the javascript function.

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: we are blind, 99% of the time we can only work code in SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable input fields and such in your javascript function **before** the data gets posted, it simply doesn't put the values of the disabled input fields in the $_POST array.

One possible way to solve this would be sending them manually.

Comment: oh, ok.
That seemed to be the problem!
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

What you may be meaning to do is listen to the submit event of the form itself. Try `.submit()` http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Edit: However, the `.click()` callback does occur before the form is submitted, so the problem could be in the manner in which you are setting your inputs.